# Getting com.android.volley.ClientError in my android API calling using volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I am a new guy in android and trying to make a rest api call using volley.
I am getting "com.android.volley.ClientError" in my code. Can anyone help me to solve this please.

```
 private void LoginByNet(String uID, String pSD){
        String URL = "http://myipaddress:65017/api/values";
        RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonObjectRequest jq = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,
                URL,
                null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success:"+response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error:"+ error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        userName.setText(error.toString());
                    }
                }
        );
        rq.add(jq);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that the server returned a 4xx error code.

[https://github.com/google/volley/blob/d1a3d5388c79ff1a6fdb904daeff9b39d0bb7d26/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/BasicNetwork.java#L199][1]

You can get the exact error code using : #error.networkResponse.statusCode

Comment: So what is the error code that you get in volley error? Without the error code its impossible to find what is wrong here.

Comment: I am getting error 500. But in postman it's success. I am confused why it's giving 500 error inside my android code.

Comment: 500 is internal server error. Probably you can debug from your server. This would give you the diff.